# pandas value_counts with bins applied to a groupby produces incorrect results

Tags: python, pandas

I can't see why value_counts is giving me the wrong answer. Here is a small example:

```
In [81]: d=pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[1,100],[0,100],[2,0],[3,100],[4,100],[4,100],[4,100],[1,100],[3,100]],columns=['key','score'])

In [82]: d
Out[82]:
   key  score
0    0      0
1    1    100
2    0    100
3    2      0
4    3    100
5    4    100
6    4    100
7    4    100
8    1    100
9    3    100

In [83]: g=d.groupby('key')['score']
In [84]: g.value_counts(bins=[0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100])
Out[84]:
key  score
0    (-0.001, 20.0]    1
     (20.0, 40.0]      1
     (40.0, 60.0]      0
     (60.0, 80.0]      0
     (80.0, 100.0]     0
1    (20.0, 40.0]      2
     (-0.001, 20.0]    0
     (40.0, 60.0]      0
     (60.0, 80.0]      0
     (80.0, 100.0]     0
2    (-0.001, 20.0]    1
     (20.0, 40.0]      0
     (40.0, 60.0]      0
     (60.0, 80.0]      0
     (80.0, 100.0]     0
3    (20.0, 40.0]      2
     (-0.001, 20.0]    0
     (40.0, 60.0]      0
     (60.0, 80.0]      0
     (80.0, 100.0]     0
4    (20.0, 40.0]      3
     (-0.001, 20.0]    0
     (40.0, 60.0]      0
     (60.0, 80.0]      0
     (80.0, 100.0]     0
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

The only values that occur in these data are 0 and 100. But value_counts tells me the range (20.0,40.0] has the most values and (80.0,100.0] has none.

Of course my real data has more values, different keys, etc. but this illustrates the problem I am seeing.

Why?

Comment: Just submitted bug report [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32471)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it to keep the integrity of the indexes.

```
d.groupby('key')['score'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts, bins=[0,20,40,60,80,100])
```

Output:

```
key                
0    (80.0, 100.0]     1
     (-0.001, 20.0]    1
     (60.0, 80.0]      0
     (40.0, 60.0]      0
     (20.0, 40.0]      0
1    (80.0, 100.0]     2
     (60.0, 80.0]      0
     (40.0, 60.0]      0
     (20.0, 40.0]      0
     (-0.001, 20.0]    0
2    (-0.001, 20.0]    1
     (80.0, 100.0]     0
     (60.0, 80.0]      0
     (40.0, 60.0]      0
     (20.0, 40.0]      0
3    (80.0, 100.0]     2
     (60.0, 80.0]      0
     (40.0, 60.0]      0
     (20.0, 40.0]      0
     (-0.001, 20.0]    0
4    (80.0, 100.0]     3
     (60.0, 80.0]      0
     (40.0, 60.0]      0
     (20.0, 40.0]      0
     (-0.001, 20.0]    0
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this and for reporting the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, this may be some bug in index alignment. A way around is to `groupby().value_counts()` on `cut`:

```
(pd.cut(d.score, bins=[0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
       include_lowest=True)
   .groupby(d['key'])
   .value_counts()
)
```

Output:

```
key  score         
0    (-0.001, 20.0]    1
     (80.0, 100.0]     1
1    (80.0, 100.0]     2
2    (-0.001, 20.0]    1
3    (80.0, 100.0]     2
4    (80.0, 100.0]     3
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to accept the other solution because it maintains the shape of my data.